# Angular 6 with php/mysql - Post method not working in server

Tags: php, angular

I am new angular developer, test app is working fine in localhost. but in the server http post, put, delete all not working. server return 403 forbidden error and also blocked my ip if hitting the page frequently.

**TypeScript:**

```
addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero>{
const url = `${this.apiUrl}post.php`;
return this.http.post<Hero>(url, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
  tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`Added id ${hero.id}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
);
}
```

**PHP:**

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add a the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST)`, `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump(fopen("php://input", "r"))`

Comment: @tam did you ever find a solution to this issue. My angular post to php on my local server works fine, but once I pushed to production, PHP is no longer seeing the post only from angular - postman to PHP works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$data = $_POST;
```

instead.

$_POST is an array with the post data.

Comment: content type is json in the angular service page, in this case $_POST is not working